ProcessBuilder cannot run program found in PATH
I'm trying to run npm through ProcessBuilder.start(). However, in Windows at least, whenever I try to start the process without stating the full path of the executable, the invocation fails with "CreateProcess error=2".
EDIT: the directory of npm is in the PATH environment variable.
Sample code:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Won't work
        invokeCommand(new String[] {"npm", "--version"});

        // Will work
        invokeCommand(new String[] {"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm.cmd", "--version"});
    }

    private static void invokeCommand(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("INVOKING: " + String.join(" ", args));

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();

            dumpStdout(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void dumpStdout(Process p) throws IOException {
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("STDOUT: " + line);
        }

        reader.close();
    }
}

Why is it so? Is it because npm is a batch command? That's very inconvenient, not to say inconsistent with other programs like java or node that will run just fine without their full paths. Thank you.

have you tried "npm.cmd"?

@user85421 that's something I would try to avoid because the program will run on different OSs, but it looks like a minor trade-off.

I think that "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm.cmd" is as bad if not worse regarding OS dependency... just asked to try, never mind

Java does scan the Path for executables, but does not reference the PATHEXT variable. So change your launcher with the file extension of the executable - which is why it works with appending ".cmd".
It would work with the extension {"npm.cmd", "--version"}, or without the extension if you use a terminal such as {"cmd.exe", "/c", yourcommand} as CMD scans the file extensions in the environment variable PATHEXT. Typically set to:
 PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC


Thank you. I will probably have to ensure that the correct file extension is appended when on Windows; that's somewhat undesirable but it's no big problem.
